# Max connections on localhost

Tags: c++

Why does my server socket, listening with `listen(severFd,2)` work with 3 terminals connected?

It should limit to 2. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Unsure if C++ is correct tag for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `listen()` states the maximum number of queued incoming requests. It is not a maximum on the number of connections that can be accepted.

From [man listen](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) (where *backlog* is the name of the second argument):

> The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the queue of pending connections for sockfd may grow.

If a maximum of two accepted connections is required then you must code that explicitly.